# font-awesome not working in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, font-awesome

I have a wordpress site and I installed the shortcode plugin.
I am trying to install a button and I put an icon on it.
When I load my site here you can see it under the slider, the button that says photo gallery
http://denverkollel.org/site/
it's on the blue background. You see there is a space , but no icon showing.
I have the font-awesome css on the page. what else might I be missing to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the older verion of Font-Awesome and that doesn't suppot `fa fa-video-camera`.
Actually, it doesn't even support `fa` class.. Initially Font-awesone used to have classes starting with `.icon-`.

Download a new version and make required changes.